# How to synchronize a list of related entities .NET EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two entity classes that look like this:

```
  public class VendorLocation
    {
        //Primary Key
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }


        public Vendor Vendor { get; set; }

        //Location address
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Vendor
    {
        //Primary Key
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        //List of locations for this vendor
        public List<VendorLocation> Locations { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, there is a one-to-many relationship such that a vendor can have many locations. I have a web form that contains a list of locations for a single `Vendor`. When the user submits the page, it submits the entire list of locations to the `Controller`. The Controller does some logic to map the ViewModel to a list of `VendorLocation`'s. My Service layer is then responsible for synchronizing the updated list of locations on the vendor:

```
  public async Task<Entities.Vendor> SetVendorLocationsAsync(Entities.Vendor vendor, List<Entities.VendorLocation> locations)
    {

        //Input locations should already have an ID if they are existing in the DB, so we can simple sync the whole list here
        vendor.Locations = locations;

        await _repository.UpdateAsync(vendor);
        return vendor;
    }
```

The `UpdateAsync` Code looks like this:

```
  /**
        *  Save an updated model to persistence
        */
        public async Task UpdateAsync(TEntity model)
        {
            _context.Update(model);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); 
        }
```

In the above code, each `VendorLocation` will have it's `Id` set to the existing `Id`in the database if the user had updated a location. Any new locations would have an `Id` of zero.

According to the Documentation ([EF Core - Disconnected Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#mix-of-new-and-existing-entities)) it says the following:

> With auto-generated keys, Update can again be used for both inserts
>   and updates, even if the graph contains a mix of entities that require
>   inserting and those that require updating.

However, I receive the exception:
`MySqlException: Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY'`

The aforementioned documentation specifically says:

> Update will mark any entity in the graph, blog or post, for insertion
>   if it does not have a key value set, while all other entities are
>   marked for update.

I would assume since my object already has an `Id` set that EF Core would flag it as an update. Why is it trying to insert again? Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: What is the code of `UpdateAsync` and which key is duplicated?

Comment: @GertArnold Edited the post to show that code

Comment: Might be a bug in MySQL provider, because it works as expected with SqlServer (EF Core 2.0.3)